# How can you programmatically tell whether or not a work.com license exists?

Tags: apex, soql

How can you programmatically tell whether or not a work.com license exists?

Is that information in `PackageLicense`, `PermissionSetLicense`, or somewhere else?

Or perhaps I'm going about it the wrong way, and it's actually by user, and not by company?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information is on the User object in the field UserPermissionsWorkDotComUserFeature.I was having issues with querying this field though. You may be able to extract this information using Dataloader.

Comment: Is there any indication that the account itself has a work.com license, or is it strictly by user?

Comment: @Houseman I've only ever seen it on the User object. I looked at Account and Person Account documentation and no Work.com indicator was there.